# basic chessboard exercise not working

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure why my code works the first two lines then says 'undefined' the last few. Its supposed to be a pattern that goes for 8 lines.

```
var x = console.log(" # # # #");
var y = console.log("# # # # ");
for (var i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
  if(i % 2 == 0){
    console.log(y);
  }
  else{
  console.log(x);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing out a console.log.

**try**

```
var x = " # # # #";
var y = "# # # # ";
for (var i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
  if(i % 2 == 0){
    console.log(y);
  }
  else{
  console.log(x);
}
}
```

**or maybe you intended to do the following:**

```
var x = function(){ console.log(" # # # #") };
var y =  function(){ console.log("# # # # ")};
for (var i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
  if(i % 2 == 0){
    y();
  }
  else{
  x();
}
}
```

**Why is your code not working?**

when you declare:

```
   var x = console.log(" # # # #"); // <- THE STRING IS BEING PRINTED OUT AT THIS POINT. NOT IN THE FOR LOOP.
```

console.log is a function which returns undefined. Therefore x is undefined.

Comment: I am just new to coding so I am just trying to figure it out. But your second example using a function is interesting thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Because `console.log` returns `undefined`.
Try this:

```
var x = " # # # #";
var y = "# # # # ";
for (var i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
  if(i % 2 == 0){
    console.log(y);
  }
  else{
  console.log(x);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Is that what you're looking for?

```
var x = " # # # #";
var y = "# # # # ";
for (var i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
  if(i % 2 == 0){
    console.log(y);
  } else{
    console.log(x);
  }
}
```

Your code is throwing undefined as you're trying to get the value of `console.log();`

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = " # # # #";
```

Don't put the console.log in the variable declaration.